# Markdown parser supports code fence with three backticks, but it's crashed by a blankline

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown, frontend, pagedown

The Stack Exchange’s Markdown parser only allows four-space indents to represent code blocks, but many other Markdown converters support Code Fence with 3 backticks, such as CommonMark, Github flavored Markdown.

So I wanna add this feature to this [Markdown.Converter.js](https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown), it works well with code block without any blankline. **But if a blankline in the code block, this Fence will be crashed (captured screen as follow)**. Here is _DoCodeFence function for this feature:

`` function _DoCodeFence(text) {
    text = text.replace(/(^|[^\\`])(`{3,})(\n)(?!`)([^\r]*?[^`])\2(?!`)/gm,
        function (wholeMatch, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5) {
            var c = m4;
            c = c.replace(/^([ \t]*)/g, "");
            c = c.replace(/[ \t]*$/g, "");
            c = _EncodeCode(c);
            c = c.replace(/:\/\//g, "~P");
            return m1 + "<pre><code>" + c + "</code></pre>";
        }
    );
    return text;
} ``

[image]

Comment: I tried to create a regex fiddle for the current regex and it seems it does not match the second block, and it happens due to the last lookahead. Remove the last `(?!\`)` and the second block will be matched.

Comment: I've tried to remove the last `(?!`)`,  the Fence will still be crashed when inserting a blankline into the Code Block.

Comment: Just see [this version without the last lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/y2ZsT8/1). It is not quite clear why it crashes as your code in the question cannot be run. Note that `c.replace(/[ \t]*$/g, "")` must be written as `c.replace(/[ \t]+$/g, "")` (change `*` to `+`) (same should be done to the `^` part, or they can be written as 1 `replace` using `|`).

Comment: Yes, this is pretty confused. I've tried your advice above, the fence crashes again. BTW, The Asking Question Form on stackoverflow.com has the same problem.

Comment: I see, it really does not format multiline block as a code. What are the requirements for this pattern? Let's re-create it from scratch.

Comment: Please [check **this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s426wL13/2/).

Comment: I've pasted the code from the fiddle, the fence crashes as the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157287/discussion-between-rogwan-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: So, the fiddle is correct, shall I post?

Comment: Yes, your example is correct, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the regex the following way:

````js
function _DoCodeFence(text) {
    text = text.replace(/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)(`{3,})(\r?\n)(?!`)([^\r]*?[^`])\2(?!`)/gm,
        function (wholeMatch, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5) {
            var c = m4;
            c = c.replace(/^[^\S\r\n]+|[^\S\r\n]+$/g, "");
            //c = _EncodeCode(c);
            c = c.replace(/:\/\//g, "~P");
            return m1 + "<pre><code>" + c + "</code></pre>";
        }
    );
    return text;
}
console.log(_DoCodeFence("\\\\```\n code\n   here\n```\n\n```\nCODE\n\n   HERE\n```"));
````

**Regex details**

- `((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)` - Group 1: start of a line (`^`) or (`|`) any char other than `\` (`[^\\]`) followed with 0+ sequences of 2 `\` chars (it is used to make sure the `` ` `` is not escaped)
- `` (`{3,}) `` - Group 2: three or more backticks
- `` (\r?\n)(?!`) `` - Group 3: a line break (CRLF or LF) not followed with a backtick
- `` ([^\r]*?[^`]) `` - Group 4: any 0+ chars other than CR as few as possible and then a char other than a backtick
- `` \2(?!`) `` - Same value as captured in Group 2 not followed with a backtick.